# Identify a fantasy / cosmic horror game from its gods

Tags: product-identification

I'm not even 100% sure this is from an RPG, but I think so...

Years ago, I came across an RPG in PDF form. The reason I'm not confident that's what it was is because I can't remember any of the "game" aspects. I thought the descriptions of its elder gods / cosmic horrors sounded cool, so I wrote some of them down. Now, trying to remember what I wrote...

- There was an ancient named Zarkolep or something similar
- Another ancient named Narcisst or similar
- Another named something vaguely like Evalinge
- There were several more, 6-8 ancients total
- One described as "the half become one drinker of worlds"
- Another had two tails
- One was the last survivor of the destroyed universe of Denhzaz (?)
- Another was described as the ancient most likely to destroy our universe
- Most of them wanted to consume / drain / assimilate the universe in some fashion; one wanted to destroy it without gaining anything

With an exact quote I'm confident of and this much specific information, I can only guess that the game isn't online anymore. It was an indie / self-published game.

Comment: Does the name 'Nyarlathotep' ring a bell from that RPG? It sounds like you're describing a Lovecraft-inspired game.

Comment: Or just Lovecraft.

Comment: It was clearly Lovecraft-inspired, but I don't recall it using any Mythos names I know.

Answer (score 4):

Without exact spelling of words, your question is pretty difficult. There are a lot of games with elder gods seeking to destroy the universe.

Google says "Drinker of Worlds" is a demon from the [Blood Storm](http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/Malus_Darkblade) storyline in Warhammer.

Comment: The big Warhammer baddies are Tzeentch, Nurgle, Khorne and Slaanesh...  Poke around in http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Warhammer_40k_Wiki and see if that rings a bell.

Comment: Coincidentally, I was reading that wiki a few days ago. No, nothing like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [Necoho the Doubter](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Necoho) and [Zuvassin the Great Undoer](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Zuvassin) from *Something Rotten in Kislev*? [SRiK](http://ageofravens.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/something-rotten-in-kislev-reading.html) is a Warhammer Fantasy RP module.

Comment: Could you briefly describe Somethign Rotten in Kislev such that it would seem to generally match the game described in the question? (Mind you, being a module for another game would correspond well with being unable to remember the game rules -- there would be little to none to remember.)

Comment: http://ageofravens.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/something-rotten-in-kislev-reading.html

Comment: I'm not sure if that link's a response to me or not, but I mean you should edit your answer to actually elaborate on *Something Rotten in Kislev* a bit. A good product identification answer generally describes the way the product matches the querent's description, such that a reader can go "oh! yes! that's the product!". Otherwise they may need to go to great lengths with their own independent research, possibly buy sourcebooks etc, when it might not be the right product.

Comment: Those names sound unfamiliar, and the art and description in that blog post ring no bells.